# PRESTASHOP cannot access carier, stock and warehouse

Tags: prestashop-1.6, stock, warehouse

I cannot access carrier, stock and warehouse from BO, it threws this kind of error and I don't understand what this error is all about. Kindly please guide me because I'm quite new with prestashop. Please refer to the image link below to see the error:

[image: image.png]

**[PrestaShopDatabaseException]**
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2

**SELECT * FROM `ps_hook_module_exceptions`
                WHERE `id_shop` IN ()**

**at line 791 in file classes/db/Db.php**

786. if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
787. $dbg = debug_backtrace();
788. WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
789. } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
790. if ($sql) {
791. throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'

     ```
     '.$sql.'
     ```

     ');
792. }
793. 794. throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
794. }
795. }

**DbCore->displayError - [line 425 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]**

420. $this->result = $this->_query($sql);
421. }
422. }
423. 424. if (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_) {
424. $this->displayError($sql);
425. }
426. 428. return $this->result;
427. }
  430.

Argument [0]

SELECT * FROM `ps_hook_module_exceptions`
                WHERE `id_shop` IN ()

**DbCore->query - [line 643 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]**

638. throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException('Db->executeS() must be used only with select, show, explain or describe queries');
639. }
640. return $this->execute($sql, $use_cache);
641. }
642. 643. $this->result = $this->query($sql);
643. 645. if (!$this->result) {
644. $result = false;
645. } else {
646. if (!$array) {
     Argument [0]

SELECT * FROM `ps_hook_module_exceptions`
                WHERE `id_shop` IN ()

**DbCore->executeS - [line 2142 - classes/module/Module.php] - [2 Arguments]**

2137. if (!Cache::isStored($cache_id)) {
2138. $exceptions_cache = array();
2139. $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'hook_module_exceptions`
2140. WHERE `id_shop` IN ('.implode(', ', Shop::getContextListShopID()).')';
2141. $db = Db::getInstance();
2142. $result = $db->executeS($sql, false);
2143. while ($row = $db->nextRow($result)) {
2144. if (!$row['file_name']) {
2145. continue;
2146. }
2147. $key = $row['id_hook'].'-'.$row['id_module'];

Argument [0]

SELECT * FROM `ps_hook_module_exceptions`
                WHERE `id_shop` IN ()
Argument [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVnOr.png)

**ModuleCore::getExceptionsStatic - [line 495 - classes/Hook.php] - [2 Arguments]**
490.                 continue;
491.             }
492. 
493.             // Check permissions
494.             if ($check_exceptions) {
495.                 $exceptions = Module::getExceptionsStatic($array['id_module'], $array['id_hook']);
496. 
497.                 $controller = Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController();
498.                 $controller_obj = Context::getContext()->controller;
499. 
500.                 //check if current controller is a module controller
Argument [0]
63
Argument [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVnOr.png)
57

**HookCore::exec - [line 2749 - classes/controller/AdminController.php] - [2 Arguments]**

2744. 'host_mode' => defined('_PS_HOST_MODE_') ? 1 : 0,
2745. 'stock_management' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')
2746. ));
2747. 2748. if ($this->display_header) {
2748. $this->context->smarty->assign('displayBackOfficeHeader', Hook::exec('displayBackOfficeHeader', array()));
2749. }
2750. 2752. $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
2751. 'displayBackOfficeTop' => Hook::exec('displayBackOfficeTop', array()),
2752. 'submit_form_ajax' => (int)Tools::getValue('submitFormAjax')
      Argument [0]
      displayBackOfficeHeader
      Argument [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVnOr.png)
      Array
      (
      )

**AdminControllerCore->init - [line 170 - classes/controller/Controller.php]**

165. /**
166. - Starts the controller process (this method should not be overridden!)
167. */
168. public function run()
169. {
170. $this->init();
171. if ($this->checkAccess()) {
172. // setMedia MUST be called before postProcess
173. if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_header || (isset($this->className) && $this->className))) {
174. $this->setMedia();
175. }

**ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]**

362. if (isset($params_hook_action_dispatcher)) {
363. Hook::exec('actionDispatcher', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);
364. }
365. 366. // Running controller
366. $controller->run();
367. } catch (PrestaShopException $e) {
368. $e->displayMessage();
369. }
370. }
  372.

**DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 58 - admin/index.php]**

53. if (!isset($_REQUEST['controller']) && isset($_REQUEST['tab'])) {
54. $_REQUEST['controller'] = strtolower($_REQUEST['tab']);
55. }
56. 57. // Prepare and trigger admin dispatcher
57. Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();

Comment: Don't post code or error messages as pictures, use text instead.

Comment: alright, done edited the question

Comment: Are you in a multi-store enviroment? It seems to be related to a non active shop_id.

You can check the DB table ps_shop, and verify if the current shop have field active = 1.